# fstab doesn't mount CIFS but mount -a after logging in works

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

This is my `fstab`:

```
UUID=64383220-a185-4473-b3ab-ef1612d4d94c / ext4 defaults,noatime,nodiratime,commit=600,errors=remount-ro 0 1

tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid 0 0

/var/swap none swap sw 0 0

//192.168.1.162/Storage/Deluge /home/armPi/Deluge cifs username=user,password=0,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

However this doesn't mount the share. I have to log in after every reboot and manually run `sudo mount -a` to mount the share.

Anyone see what's wrong? I'm guessing I messed something up in the OS, and need to reinstall everything.

Comment: Maybe put mount at the end of the boot sequence, like in /etc/rc.local.

Comment: @ubfan1 don't you need to be root to mount a share? 

I added `sudo mount -a` to my /etc/rc.local but that didn't do anything.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your mount as it looks pretty close to mine.  I do, however, add the `nofail` option to the line.  That is so that if the network is not available at the time of when it is looking for the mount, it doesn't error.  Other than that, I really wouldn't know.

Comment: Anything run in rc.local is run as root, so no sudo is necessary.  Maybe add a test if the network is available, if not sleep(? but that may be a bad idea), and try again some limited number of times or until avail, then do the mount.